# change width within \newtheoremstyle

Tags: newtheorem, adjustwidth

I've defined a new theorem environment which is surrounded by a shaded box.
My code looks like this:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{framed}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{gray!50}
\newtheoremstyle{mythm}
    {0.3\topsep} % space above
    {0.3\topsep} % space below
    {} % body font
    {} % indentation
    {\bfseries} % theorem head font
    {.} % punctuation after theorem head
    { } % space after theorem head
    {} % head spec

\theoremstyle{mythm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{משפט}
\renewenvironment{thm}
   {\begin{shaded}\begin{theorem}}
   {\end{theorem}\end{shaded}}
```

(I'm using the hebrew word משפט for theorem). Now, when I use the thm environment, this is how it looks like:

[image]

As you can see, the width of a line inside the box matches the width of a normal line. My question is: how can I redefine it such that the width of **the shaded box itself** will match the width of a normal line?
I couldn't find any width parameter of newtheoremstyle, so help will be welcomed.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! If the width of the box is the same as the width of the line, the start of משפט will be on the edge of the box, and similarly if the theorem spans a full line (or multiple lines) then the end of the line will be also on the edge of the box. Is this desired (genuine question, maybe it is desired, maybe it is not)?

Comment: @Marijn Thanks! The answer is no, I want to keep the horizontal margin inside the box. So the width of the box is equal to width of a normal line, but the width of a line inside the box is shorter.

Comment: Please add a complete minimal working example, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`